Shrinker R8 crashes on start MAUI application in release mode
When app start I get exception. When I select shrinker=none, everything is fine.

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: _v_2.x_0, PID: 8363
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no
"Landroidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences$PrefKeyEncryptionScheme;"
field "AES256_SIV" in class
"Landroidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences$PrefKeyEncryptionScheme;"
or its superclasses


You can refer to this issue: App crashes on startup when R8 shrinker is set in Maui - Release mode #13413.
